# How to import/consume webjars in Spring MVC 3.2.6?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, webjars

I am unable to consume font-awesome.4.4.0 webjars to my SPring MVC 3.2.6 + Tomcat7 project.But I am able to consume via CDN, though i don't want dependencies.

pom.xml

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
     <artifactId>font-awesome</artifactId>
     <version>4.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

In servlet-config.xml I have the following code,

```
<mvc:resources location="pdfs" mapping="/pdfs/**" />
 <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/theme1/"/>
 <mvc:resources mapping="/webjars/**" location="classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/"/>
```

In my login.jsp i am trying to access the font-awesome.css like below,

```
<link href="/webjars/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

(or)

```
<link href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/webjars/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

(or)

```
<link href="<c:url value='/webjars/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.css' />" rel="stylesheet">
```

I followed the below link but no luck,

[Webjar Documentation](http://www.webjars.org/documentation)

Also i tried using weblocater,

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
<artifactId>webjars-locator</artifactId>
<version>0.1</version>
```

Provided resources in servlet-config.xml and in my login.jsp i access the file using below,

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='<%= org.webjars.AssetLocator.getWebJarPath("css/font-awesome.css") %>'>
```

Please find the below web.xml,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern> 
</filter-mapping>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/config/security-config.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>taskManagementServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/config/servlet-config.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>taskManagementServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>taskManagementServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.json</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>taskManagementServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/pdfs/**</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>1</session-timeout> 
</session-config>
</web-app>
```

Please guide me to correct the bug.

Comment: What's the version of your servlet container? Or better then, what's your deployment descriptor (`web.xml`) version? The configuration looks fine to me...

Comment: No Luck i tried <link rel="stylesheet" href="webjars/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.css"> but still i am unable to see the icon in screen.

Comment: This works: `<link rel="stylesheet" href='<c:url value="/webjars/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.css" />'>` in my project...

Comment: Yes i tried try this, In the question itself i specified it doesn't works.In the chrome console i saw the following URL `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/TaskManagement/webjars/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.css">`

Comment: In the browser (Blink-powered or Firefox), open up the `Developer Console`, select the `Network` tab and see if what are the resources that loads when you go to that page

Comment: Hi In Firefox i am able to see the icon,But in firefox developer console i saw the following status for font-awesome.css,`302 moved Temporarily`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86658/discussion-between-velnaga-and-auiham).

Comment: Have a look at this [project](https://bitbucket.org/vadimvera/spring-mvc)...I'm already using webjars; you can play with it. Like I said, your configuration looks fine...

Comment: Thank you.For the Past 5 Hours i am fighting with this everything seems fine but i am unable to see the icons.And it returns status code as `302 moved temporarily`.

Comment: Hi I am able to see the icons in screen.I compare the web.xml with your s,found i am using 2.5 after replacing DTD with yours(3.1).Then I made the following modification in servlet-config.xml `<mvc:resources mapping="/webjars/**" location="/webjars/"/>`.it works.But excluding login.jsp i am able to see the icons in other jsps. Why login.jsp alone not loading the icons this is because spring-security issue?I am using spring-security for login purpose.Could you please clarify why icons are not loaded in login.jsp?

Comment: In the login.jsp alone i am getting `302 moved Temporarily` issue.How to resolve this?

Comment: Try to render the `login.jsp` alone without any security involved and see what happens...then you can say is Spring Security or not who's restricting that resource; but I think you should have a rule/directive to be able to load "static" resources (regardless of the user/role/permissions depending on the nature of your application, of course)